# MySQL: Multiple SELECTs with different WHEREs on same field with result in separate columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have read numerous questions regarding similar scenarios but can't quite seem to find a solution.

I have the following query to get cumulated timetrackings (stop and start are UNIX timestamps) per user per calendar week, separated by type of timetracking (project time, driving time etc.)

```
SELECT 
u.login as Person,
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(t.start), '%x-%v') as CalendarWeek,
t.tracking_type as TrackingType,
REPLACE(ROUND(SUM(stop-start) / 60 / 60, 2), '.', ',') AS TimeHrs
FROM ps_time_tracking t
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON (u.id = t.user_id)
GROUP BY Person, CalendarWeek, TrackingType
ORDER BY CalendarWeek ASC, Person ASC
```

The result looks like this:

```
| Person | CalendarWeek | TrackingType | TimeHrs | 
| ------------------------------------------------
| User A | 2018-01      | project time | 31,82   | 
| User A | 2018-01      | driving time | 4,75    | 
| User B | 2018-01      | project time | 60,17   | 
| User B | 2018-01      | driving time | 9,02    | 
| User C | 2018-01      | project time | 7,33    |
```

The goal would be to put the result of multiple WHEREs such as

```
WHERE t.tracking_type = 'project time'
WHERE t.tracking_type = 'driving time'
```

in different result columns:

```
| Person | CalendarWeek | TrackingType | ProjectTime | DrivingTime |
| --------------------------------------------------------------------
| User A | 2018-01      | project time | 31,82       | 4,75        |
| User B | 2018-01      | project time | 60,17       | 9,02        |
| User C | 2018-01      | project time | 7,33        | (null)      |
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use a `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` to get what you need. It would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
u.login as Person,
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(t.start), '%x-%v') as CalendarWeek,
REPLACE(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN TrackingType = 'project time' THEN stop-start ELSE 0 END) / 60 / 60, 2), '.', ',') AS ProjectTime,
REPLACE(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN TrackingType = 'driving time' THEN stop-start ELSE 0 END) / 60 / 60, 2), '.', ',') AS DrivingTime
FROM ps_time_tracking t
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON (u.id = t.user_id)
GROUP BY Person, CalendarWeek
ORDER BY CalendarWeek ASC, Person ASC
```